# Share content types between site collections without Content Type Hub

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, content-type, content-type-hub

Is it possible to share content types across site collections without the content type hub?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create a site collection scoped feature that would create them and add them to the content type gallery if you are not going to use a content type hub. This makes upkeep much more complex, so I'd encourage the use of a hub if possible.

Comment: I'm fairly new to SharePoint and I'm not sure about this but it looks like the ability to deploy custom site collection features is only available in the Server edition. If that is the case it would be better to just use the content type hub.

Comment: You can still create site collection scoped features for Foundation

Answer (score 0):

I think Content Type hub is best solution because even you can create content types using features across site collections, however any updates made to the content types cannot be easily propogated to different site collections.

Only CTH will give you this functionality.

[Content Types Synchronization across Site Collections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/neha_bajpai/archive/2009/05/26/content-types-synchronization-across-site-collections.aspx)

Comment: I would ideally like to use the Content Type Hub, however I do not have the SharePoint Server license, only the Foundations.

Comment: then i think Office 365 is good alternate.